# nginx websocket reverse proxy configuration

Tags: nginx, websocket

Hi I am trying to configure nginx as reverse proxy for websockets. I configure my server as following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;

    access_log  off;
    #error_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8765;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_buffering off;
    }

}
```

but I get an error from client like following

WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.application.com/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'

I am probably doing some configuration wrong but I could not see it.

Request headers for client is following

```
GET ws://www.talkybee.com/ws HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: http://www.talkybee.com
Host: www.talkybee.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Ol+O1IdaLEsHxxWRBt2oqg==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

When I do a normal direct connection, My connection just works. Here is the working request header.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:www.talkybee.com:8765
Origin:http://www.talkybee.com:8765
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:Y026b/84aUkMxVb0MaKE2A==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: what happens if you just try `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8765/;`

Comment: @rednaw I am getting the same exception. I changed the config in the question with current one.

Comment: Is your client also setting the `Connection` header to `Upgrade`?

Comment: @rednaw. Yes It seems like it has connection:Upgrade header. I will try to get diff of working direct connection header and proxied header.

Comment: @rednaw looks like I am missing Sec-WebSocket-Key: header. I guess I should find a way to mass those headers too.

Comment: well I just saw the webdocket-key in the header. The difference is broken one does a http request instead of a websocket one.

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin can you post your solution for this? I have the same problem but I cannot upgrade to nginx 1.4 at this time

Answer (score 21):

This issue is related with the nginx version. Pleas check nginx -v, to check your version.
The followings params are supported after the **1.4** version.

```
 # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

If you are using ubuntu you can install a newer version with this steps:

First remove the old version (https://askubuntu.com/questions/235347/what-is-the-best-way-to-uninstall-nginx):

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then install a new version (https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/development):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: I had that problem too but I solve this by upgrading my nginx server (~$ nginx -v)
(nginx version: nginx/1.5.1)

Comment: The solution I had for this problem was connecting direct port for websocket. So my site is on port:80 but my websocket connection goes to port:8765 looks like websocket does not have a cross domain restriction afterall.