# configure nginx for socket io

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have a node js app that is running on port 3000. I'm using socket io which is configured to use port 4000

Socket IO Connection (node app)

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(4000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   ...


});
```

My front end code connects to localhost:4000 which work fine when running locally.

```
globals.socket = io.connect(":4000");
```

But on production everything is going through port 80... not sure how to configure my nginx to send the right stuff to port 3000 and the socket stuff through port 4000... Below is what I have for part of my nginx config

```
 server {
            listen                  80;
            server_name             someurl.com;
            location / {
                   proxy_pass      http://localhost:3000;
                    proxy_buffering on;


                    }

    }
```

How can I set this up to work? I tried two proxy_passes, but that didn't work... Not sure where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: see [nginx-websocket-reverse-proxy-configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427303/nginx-websocket-reverse-proxy-configuration)

Comment: That's not really the same, I'm not running my app on port 80 and I have 1 proxy pass set up already.

Comment: nginx version? ws proxy is only available since v. 1.4 or 1.3

Comment: 1.1.19... hmm I guess I should update?